# Tensor Product of two doublets

Tags: tensor-calculus

What will be the tensor product of two doublets
$$
(x_1,x_2) ~\text{and}~ (y_1,y_2)?
$$
I am very much confused in determining this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give a simpler (and, surely, more naiive) answer.
 Given two n-tuplets $x_i$ and $y_j$, their tensor product is a matrix:
$$a_{ij} = x_iy_j$$
So, in your case:
$$a_{ij} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}x_1y_1&x_1y_2\\x_2y_1&x_2y_2\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Right, maybe the OP wanted the tensor product of the particular vectors... Good point.

Comment: Is there any difference between tensor product and Kronecker Product?

Comment: @MANIKANTABORAH You are drifting into the math direction. I'd say that you should investigate it on math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

The doublets – I assume that you mean 2-dimensional representations of $SU(2)\equiv Spin(3)$ – are spin-1/2 representation. Tensor products mean the addition of the angular momentum. The tensor product is 4-dimensional and under $SU(2)$, it decomposes to a $j=0$ multiplet, a scalar or singlet, and a $j=1$ multiplet, a vector:
$${\mathbf 2}\otimes {\mathbf 2} = {\mathbf 1}\oplus {\mathbf 3} $$
In your notation, you may write 
$$(x_1,x_2)\otimes (y_1,y_2)\mapsto ((v_1,v_2,v_3),(s)) $$